# Delete com Insert em PL/SQL com erro de FK

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Boa noite,

Tenho uma tabela que chama horariofunc e a primeiry key desta tabela está ligando na tabela de endereço.

Acontece que estou usando para atualizar os dados um delete e um insert com os novos dados. O insert possui a mesma primeira key que está sendo referenciada na tabela endereço.

Porém ao iniciar a transação, como o delete vem primeiro, sobe um erro da minha constraint de FK da tabela endereço.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma saída para essa situação, sem remover a constraint e sem deixar de atualizar os dados com delete e insert, pois fica mais simples uma unica função para fazer os dois serviços rsrs.

SQL:

```
 begin  
    delete from cahorariofunc cahf
       where cahf.id_pessoa = 24
     and cahf.cd_horariofunc = 1;
     insert into cahorariofunc
    (id_horariofunc,
     id_pessoa,
     cd_horariofunc,
     cd_horariofunc_erp,
     ds_horariofunc,
     bo_ativo)
  values  (36, 24, 1, '1', 'PRINCIPAL', 'S');

 end;
```

Obs: Minha primary key é composta pelo id da pessoa e pelo código do horário de funcionamento.

Comment: Qual erro ? Como está a declaração "on delete" da fk ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Pelo que entendi você esta apagando e inserindo apenas para não ter o trabalho de ter de verificar se a informação existe e caso exista atualizar e caso não exista incluir, correto? Se esse for o caso você poderia simplesmente usar um o comando "merge".